# Using esc_attr or htmlspecialchars in $POST doesn't submit to DB?

Tags: php, mysql, escaping, special-characters

I want users to have the ability to enter special characters and for it to still submit to the DB.

I have tested using the input: **Dave & ' " ***, however it doesn't store in the database. If I don't use special characters as per the above and just use **Dave**, it stores just fine.

I have tried 2 things:

```
<p class="clearfix">
                        <label for="name">name</label>
                        <input class="validate[required]" id="name" name="name" type="text" value="'.esc_attr($_POST['name']).'">
                    </p>
```

and

```
<p class="clearfix">
                        <label for="name">name</label>
                        <input class="validate[required]" id="name" name="name" type="text" value="'.htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']).'">
                    </p>
```

Neither work.

Database insertion code after payment:

```
if(strpos($response['body'], 'VERIFIED') !== false && $_POST['payment_status'] == "Completed") {
    //Assign IPN Post Values to Local Variables
    $comboString = $_POST['txn_id'].$_POST['payment_date'];

    $data = explode('~',$_POST['custom']);

    $ipn_data = array(
        'name'      => mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']),
        'sale_date'     => $_POST['payment_date']
    );
    $ipn_format = array('%s','%s');
    if($ipn_business == $paypal_email) {

        $wpdb->insert($wpdb->prefix.'orderdata', $ipn_data, $ipn_format);
        $ipn_data['currency'] = $_POST['mc_currency'];
        $ipn_data['admin_field'] = $_POST['admin_field'];

        send_email($ipn_data);
    }

} else {
    exit("IPN Request Failure");
}
```

Comment: Show your code that updated the DB. If you're not using prepared statements, you need to use `mysql_real_escape_string()`.

Comment: @Barmar: Thanks Barmar, but users may enter `Dave & Jane` so I don't want to escape the &

Comment: Whoops - completely missed that. Updated the question now @Barmar. Thanks mario

Answer (score 0):

Two very simple rules for this that apply here:

1. Make strings safe for inserting into a database when, and only when, inserting in to a database
2. Make strings safe for showing on screen when, and only when, showing on screen.

(Similar rules for adding to XML, adding to URLs / GET paramteters, putting data into email etc - each had a way of handling it.)

So, when instering into a database, use PDO prepared statements or mysqli prepared statements, as this will make the data safe for you. If you can't, then wrap the string in `mysql_real_escape_string()`. It will NOT change the contents going in (and thus coming out) of the database, just make it safe to enter.

And when displaying on screen, as you have in your second example, use `htmlentities()` or `mysqlspecialchars()`. mysqlspecialchars is best if you know how to handle the quotes, but if unsure, use htmlentities.

While I'm at it, I see you're sending an e-mail. Make sure you remove linebreaks and fake boundaries from values that get added to e-mail headers, and remove fake boundaries from the body (line breaks OK). Preferably use a script for email as they are tricky to make spam proof.

Comment: Thank you for the great explanation. So realistically I should be doing this for the insert - `'name'      => mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']),
        'sale_date'     => mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['payment_date'])`?

Comment: Yes, and no. You pass ipn_data to your e-mail function, and you DO NOT want to pass mysql escaped values to that. So create yourself a copy of the parameters, and only escape the ones going into the database.

Comment: Thanks - makes sense! Trying a test now :) 1 min.

Comment: I've updated the 'name' db insertion line of code in my question. Still not inserting if I use special characters. I can make a copy of them after for the e-mail function - just trying to get this insertion happening first.

Comment: So, what is your $wpdb class doing, then? It might be doing something stupid like saying "contains dogy characters, so I'm not inserting". mysql_real_escape_string doesn't remove the characters, it makes them safe, so a secondard chack looking for such characters will still find them.

Comment: Edit: this is WordPress isn't it? In which case you DO NOT escape the parameters before input - the class does it for you. The error must lie somewhere else

Comment: I imagined using `esc_attr` would be fine as per http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/esc_attr? Yep Wordpress.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19612/discussion-between-robbie-and-dave)